# Porting Android on various other mobiles

Tags: android, motorola, motorola-droid

I am new to the development as well as the prg world. I want to learn android and want to make applications for it. So one possible way is to buy a new android phone to test it live and not on emulator. But I have two spare phones, Nokia N70 and Motorola MotoRokr E6. So I was willing to port the OS on those machines. As a result I wanted to know is that possible then what all do i need for that considering both Software and Hardware Aspects.
ThankYou in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

Its possible however I would strongly recommend against it.

While android is open source and nominally can be run on any system you choose, in reality you would have to start worrying about keyboard incompatibility, drivers for any integrated peripherals your phone has, lacking buttons that are standard to all android phones etc.

Getting android running well on one of these phones would be a large project in its own right.  I certainly wouldn't recommend testing your android apps on it as a first port of call as the problems you uncover are as likely to be with your android port as with your app.

Answer (score 0):

Neither phone has anywhere near sufficient memory.

You need 96-128 mb, preferably more like 256 mb of ram.

Something that was already linux-based would be simplest as you would start by adding the android kernel modifications.   Alternatively, something that is a winmo cousin to a vendor's existing android phone and has basically comparable hardware so you can hopefully recycle drivers or leverage an existing porting effort.

But if you need to aquire a phone anyway, get one that already runs android.